# Run the python program when the raspberry pi being start upp

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQveu.jpg)

Hello !

I am doing a project to use drone to measure the wind speed

The problem is when the drone is turn on by pressing a button. The button also triggers the raspberry pi to start up and the same time the code also needs boosting up to run the measurment. So how I can do that ?
I use the screen command on the terminal of the raspberry bi. The first PID is where I have to access to run the machine.

Comment: Set the script to be triggered on restart on your `crontab`

Comment: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8734/execute-script-on-start-up

Comment: Fits in https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8734/execute-script-on-start-up

Answer (score 1):

You can try to write a SystemD service that will start the measurement after the Raspberry Pi has booted.

```
[Unit]
Description=Measurement service

[Service]
ExecStart=/path/to/the/measurement/script.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

You can paste the above into a file under `/etc/systemd/system/measurement.service`

Make sure to mark the script that you're planning to run as executable with `chmod`

Then enable the service and start it with

```
# systemctl daemon-reload
# systemctl enable measurement.service
# systemctl start measurement.service
```

Comment: Do I write it as a python code or in the terminal window ?